# Rails form_for conditional parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, conditional-statements, form-for

I have a form, defined like this:

```
form_for(@model) do |f|
    # Really a lot happens here 
end
```

I was wondering if there is any way I can adjust the very first line: `form_for(@model)`

First I though that I might be able use a helper function:

```
def my_form
   if some_condition
      form_for(@model)
   else
      form_for [@model, @nested_model]
   end
end
```

and then embed it into my form call. Like this:

```
my_form do |f|
    # Really a lot happens here 
end
```

But, I get "**No block given**" error. Can someone point out - why and how to fix it ? Maybe there is any other approach I could use ?

Don't ask me why do I need it. Just to keep things as DRY as possible. Forms should be reusable, you know :D

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what `some_condition` is all about? Is it accessing some global information somewhere (you didn't pass it as a parameter)? You received an error because your `my_form` helper isn't designed to accept a block parameter.

Comment: @mbratch Consider "some_condition" here just as an instance variable from the view. Or a variable, passed to this helper method. Doesn't really matter. What matters is - I want to be able to switch between the "form_for"'s I have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the block to `my_form`. The way to do that is to include a `yield` where you want the block to go:

```
def my_form
   if some_condition
      form_for(@model) { |f| yield f }
   else
      form_for [@model, @nested_model] { |f| yield f }
   end
end
```

This should take the block you pass in your view:

```
my_form do |f|
    # Really a lot happens here 
end
```

Comment: Thank you so kind! Works like a charm. Could you explain, how it basically works ?

Comment: @Dmitri I added a little explanation. If you Google search "Ruby blocks" you can find lots of details on various ways of handling blocks. Otherwise, let me know if you'd like more detail.

Comment: OK, thank you. Will take a look deeper into ruby blocks! :) But, still. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not work for me